# During migration from oracle to MySQL how to compare data between two using Java

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, database-migration

I have migrated data from Oracle to MySQL using  MySQL Migration Toolkit as POC. Now I want to compare data between same tables of different databases with Java.

I have done the simple total no of rows of the tables in two database. But I want to check each and every row of two tables so that any update in any oracle table post or during migration can be figured .

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit silly, but how about a simple program which just reads both databases and compares the data?

You could write a class containing all the data from one row, override equals() and hashCode(), then read both tables and compare them using the created class.

```
public class MyRow {
    int someVal;
    String someOtherVal;
    // etc
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {} // implement this
    public int hashCode(){} // implement this
}
```

Then in your program:

```
List<MyRow> mysqlRows = readMysql();
List<MyRow> oracleRows = readOracleRows();
for (MyRow mysqlRow : mysqlRows) {
    if (!mysqlRow.equals(oracleRows.get(index)) {
        // log error
    }
}
```

Of course, you might want to consider reading the tables a row at a time, if the amount of rows is massive and memory usage is an issue.

Comment: deltaforce2,Atlast i have to do the same.Although there are challenges as the result set return of the two database are different.So map stuff are needed.anyways thanks.sorry for late reply